# React Native- Expo Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: NPM package not found:

Tags: react-native, expo

I have started many react native applications with the following code before, but now I am encountering this error (Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: NPM package not found: https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank/-/expo-template-blank-47.0.19.tgz
Error cloning template: Error: NPM package not found: https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank/-/expo-template-blank-47.0.19.tgz).

Can anyone figure out why?

Error

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
```

and `npm start` again.